# NextCloud: PHP no tiene acceso a /dev/urandom

Tags: php, permisos

Me estoy volviendo loco con este error en nextcloud:

> PHP no tiene acceso a /dev/urandom lo cual es desaconsejable por razones de seguridad

He hecho:
`rm /dev/urandom
mknod -m 777 /dev/urandom c 1 9`

Pero sigue diciéndome que no tiene acceso.

¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

En php.ini tengo:

```
open_basedir = /dev/urandom
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo arregle, en la configuración de nginx del dominio, en el apartado de open_basedir hay que dejarlo vació.